# Why can't I install two architecture versions of libi2c-dev?

Tags: 20.04, software-installation, arm, cross-compilation

I am running Ubuntu 20.04 on a 64bit ARM architecture.

I am trying to build some code which links `libi2c` (-li2c). However I want to be able to build both as local architecture and also cross compile for (in this case) `armhf`. The problem I have is that when I try to install the foreign architecture version of the library, apt wants to remove the local version (this also happens vice versa).

```
$sudo apt install libi2c-dev:armhf --no-install-recommends

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  i2c-tools libc6-dev:armhf libcrypt-dev:armhf libusb-0.1-4:armhf linux-libc-dev:armhf read-edid
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
Recommended packages:
  i2c-tools:armhf
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  libi2c-dev
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libi2c-dev:armhf
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 1 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 7244 B of archives.
After this operation, 2048 B disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] n
Abort.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be reported as bug. AFAIK, the current best option is to split arch-dependent and arch-independent headers, libs, dev executable on different package.

- arch-independent will be included in same package for all architectures
- arch-dependent, each architecture will have it's own package that could be co-installed at least with same version between architectures. Use installation path triplets.

See more [MultiarchCross](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/MultiarchCross)

As workaround, you may

1. install one architecture (native preferred)
2. manually extract other architectures

Answer (score 0):

I'm a sys admin, not a developer, so I'm not familiar with the reasoning to do multi-architecture libraries on the same host. From a sys ads perspective, I'd just use a separate virtual machine.  You may want to try out [debians multi-architecture setup here.](https://wiki.debian.org/Multiarch/HOWTO) Essentially there needs to be an emulation layer created.

Comment: A layer of emulation would significantly reduce compile time. In this situation the big advantage is compiling on a big multiprocessor machine, not a microcontroller or pi say.